# Why does go UnmarshalJSON receives Json Object and not just value

Tags: json, go

I got the following custom type:

```
type TimeWithoutZone struct {
    time.Time
}
```

The Marshaling works fine:

```
const timeWithoutZoneFormat = "2006-01-02T15:04:05"
func (t *TimeWithoutZone) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    stamp := fmt.Sprintf(`"%s"`, t.Time.Format(timeWithoutZoneFormat ))
    return []byte(stamp), nil
}
```

But here the date can not be parsed:

```
func (t *TimeWithoutZone) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) (err error) {
    log.Println("Parsing: " + string(data))
    t.Time, err = time.Parse(`"` + timeWithoutZoneFormat + `"`, string(data))

    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}
```

It logs: `Parsing: {"time":"2016-09-06T11:06:16"}` but I would expect it to parse just the value of `time`

What am I doing wrong? here is the related test:

```
type TimeTestObj struct {
    Time TimeWithoutZone `json:"time"`
}

func TestParseDataWithoutTimezone(t *testing.T) {
    parsed := TimeWithoutZone{}

    data := `{"time":"2016-09-06T11:06:16"}`
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &parsed)

    if err != nil {
        t.Error(err)
    }

    if parsed.Unix() != 1473152776 {
        t.Error(parsed.Unix(), "!=", 1473152776)
    }
}
```

All the examples I find, and even the default parser from the Go time package seem to work that way...

Answer (score 1):

Wow I just have the wrong type in this line:

```
parsed := TimeWithoutZone{}
```

must be

```
parsed := TimeTestObj{}
```

...